# Помогите что делать если иконка tkinter белая

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему когда я патаюсь установить иконку на окно она устанавливается но не отображается?

вот я добавил иконку

Icon = 'Icon.ico'

root.iconbitmap(Icon)

[image: вот фото как она выглядит]

Comment: Файл присутствует в той же директории, что и скрипт?

Comment: Как минимум стоит проверить, что у иконки действительно формат ico, а не какой-нибудь png, у которого изменили расширение.

Answer (score 0):

`root.iconphoto(False, tkinter.PhotoImage(file='Icon.png'))` только в данном случае лучше использовать заместо .ico файл .png